# Storing Data on and accessing data from a website

Tags: android, database, web, urlconnection

This is a total noob question. Sorry in advance if it is vague, but I'm looking for advice on how to start out. I have an app that I've developed that interacts with a local sqlite3 database. Everything works great, insofar as the data is local. Now, I want to move this data away from the local device and onto my website so that the app has to call out to that URL to get/set this data.

What topics should I be looking into? I need to understand how to 1) house this data on my website, and 2) modify my app to interact with it. Again, sorry if this is vague - just looking for topics to begin my search.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm finding lots of resources out there that describe how to retrieve data FROM the site. What I am really spinning my wheels on is how to modify data stored on a site. This is back end data. No one will ever see it directly. JSON format sounds like the way to go, but I don't know where to look for ideas of how to update this data after a user initiates a change from the app. I need to update the data on the site, not just on the local database. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON JSON JSON! JSON is awesome, and is IMO the easiest way to communicate between the web and any other platform. You can look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for more info on the android side. Depending on what platform you are using for your website, there are many awesome libraries to help export your info to JSON. Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of JSON but haven't used it before. I'll look into it. Any ideas of how I can use it to modify the data stored on the site? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You can post JSON back to an api call on your site and process it like you will process it on the android end. Could be as simple as an auto sync to the database.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this? What topic(s) should I be looking for? Is this SQLServer? Something else? Right now, I have only a URL that I will be building out to host this data. There is no "front end" of this site, per se. I just envision it as a place to hold the data for the app to interact with.

Comment: Oh cool! I like php ok, and its easy to learn. So, you will want to read the PHP JSON documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) and then work through this tutorial [here](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP). For storage, reference the Mysql documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) and then work through this tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp). Hooking those components together is fairly easy.

Comment: The other thing you can do is a simple http post from the app to the site and setup an api on your site to process that. Its similar to how you would intake json data, because the post data is usually encoded in json. You can read about the android http post class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html).

Comment: Thanks very much for all of your advice. I definitively have a lot to digest, but now I have somewhere to start. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Volley library as it will simplify and speed up greatly your network communications ([get it here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/)).

You probably want to use JSON to retrieve and send data to your web-service as it is very light and compact.

An [example](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android.html) using Volley and JSON

Comment: Thanks. I think that Volley might be the way to go. Still stuck on how to modify the data on the site itself. Any suggestions?